# findById() not working on spring boot and Jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

My main class is :

```
 package com.ashwin.jpafirst;

    import com.ashwin.jpafirst.model.Person;
    import com.ashwin.jpafirst.reposit.PersonJpaRepository;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class JpafirstApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

        private Logger logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

        @Autowired
        PersonJpaRepository personJpaRepository;

        public static void main(String[] args)

        {
            SpringApplication.run(JpafirstApplication.class, args);
        }

        @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            logger.info("User id is ",personJpaRepository.findById(2));

        }

    }
```

Person.java

```
package com.ashwin.jpafirst.model;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person {


        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private int id;

        @Column(name="name")
        private String name;
        private String location;
        private Date dateOfBirth;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getLocation() {
            return location;
        }
        public void setLocation(String location) {
            this.location = location;
        }
        public Date getDateOfBirth() {
            return dateOfBirth;
        }
        public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
            this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        }
        public Person(int id, String name, String location, Date dateOfBirth) {

            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.location = location;
            this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        }

        public Person() {

        }


    }
```

my application properties is:

```
## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpaintro
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password =


    ## Hibernate Properties
    # The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

    # Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

PersonJpaRepository.java

```
package com.ashwin.jpafirst.reposit;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import com.ashwin.jpafirst.model.Person;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


@Repository
@Transactional
public class PersonJpaRepository {

    //connects to Databse
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public Person findById(int id) {
        return entityManager.find(Person.class, id);
    }

}
```

I have also data saved in database as:

[image]

But when I try to receive the Person object by Id using

```
logger.info("User id is ",personJpaRepository.findById(2));
```

I am just getting as :

[image]

As Person object needs to print there,but the code is successfully compiling but I am not getting the information regarding the person.My code has no error but it is not retrieving the data.Why is the Person object not printing in the console?

Comment: Could yo activate sql log to review the query generated?

Comment: What is the purpose of `@GeneratedValue` here? Are you creating person objects, and persisting them to the database from within the application? Or does the data already exist in the database and you're just looking to retrieve it?

Comment: Did you try findAll? what is result? and please share generated sql too

Comment: i created the data into the database and want to retieve it. I am not inserting data from spring boot

Comment: The line `logger.info("User id is ",personJpaRepository.findById(2))` only prints the string `User id is`.  You need to add the parameter:  `logger.info("User id is {} ",personJpaRepository.findById(2))`

Comment: i m getting output as  User id is  com.ashwin.jpafirst.model.Person@54f6b629

Comment: So the Person object is retrieved correctly. Now just add a toString() method in the Person class to set how you want to print its data.